# asp.net MVC select list returning related value AND selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, selectlist

I have a select list where you select the location of a bus stop. I want the locations to be the select list items but I want it to return the bus stop NUMBER that is related to the location. How is this possible? Do I state it in the new SelectList()?

My routeStop Controller create function:

```
   public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["BusRouteCode"] = new SelectList(_context.BusRoute, "BusRouteCode", "BusRouteCode");
            ViewData["Location"] = new SelectList(_context.BusStop, "Location", "Location");



            return View();
        }

        // POST: DwRouteStop/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("RouteStopId,BusRouteCode,BusStopNumber,OffsetMinutes")] RouteStop routeStop)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                _context.Add(routeStop);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewData["BusRouteCode"] = new SelectList(_context.BusRoute, "BusRouteCode", "BusRouteCode", routeStop.BusRouteCode);
            ViewData["Location"] = new SelectList(_context.BusStop, "Location", "Location",  routeStop.BusStopNumberNavigation.Location);
            return View(routeStop);
        }
```

corresponding form in view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BusStopNumberNavigation.Location" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="BusStopNumberNavigation.Location" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Location"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

RouteStop model:

```
namespace DwBusService.Models
{
    public partial class RouteStop
    {
        public int RouteStopId { get; set; }
        public string BusRouteCode { get; set; }
        public int? BusStopNumber { get; set; }





        public int? OffsetMinutes { get; set; }

        public virtual BusRoute BusRouteCodeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual BusStop BusStopNumberNavigation { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Bus Stop Model:

```
namespace DwBusService.Models
{
    public partial class BusStop
    {
        public BusStop()
        {
            RouteStop = new HashSet<RouteStop>();
            TripStop = new HashSet<TripStop>();
        }

        public int BusStopNumber { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int LocationHash { get; set; }
        public bool GoingDowntown { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RouteStop> RouteStop { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TripStop> TripStop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can access both location and bus stop number through busStopNumberNavigation. I hope you can understand my question. I want to select the location and return both the location and  the bus stop number at the same time to the post action.

Comment: Is the Location and Stop number having a one to one connection (or from the same table) ? If yes, Build a SELECT element where the value is stop number and text is location.

Comment: A `<select>` element only returns one value (the `value` attribute of its selected option)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list from your `_context.BusStop` like:

```
_context.BusStopLIst=BusStops.Select(BusStop=> new { Text = BusStop.Location , Value = BusStop.BusStopNumber  });
```

Then create your `ViewData` like:

```
ViewData["BusStops"]=new SelectList(_context.BusStopLIst, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: It won't allow me to use "BusStop.Select"

Comment: you should create a list for 'BusStop' like: List<BusStop> BusStoplist and then populate that list with BusStops you like and then use `BusStoplist .Select`